# Getting absolute path to perl executable for the current process

Tags: perl, raku

Is there a way to get an *absolute* path to the Perl executable for the current process?

`$^X` will give me the Perl executable name, but the doc states that it will sometimes be a relative path, and this seems to be true on OS X for example.

`ExtUtils::MakeMaker` seems to have some magic to find the absolute path, since the Makefile it generates on my OS X contains

```
PERL = /usr/local/bin/perl
FULLPERL = /usr/local/bin/perl
```

but I have no idea how it does this or whether the magic is readily accessible to others.

EDIT: Thanks Borodin for the `$Config{perlpath}` tip. Grepping for this in `ExtUtils`, I found this tidbit in `ExtUtils::MM_Unix::_fixin_replace_shebang`, which I guess is what MakeMaker uses to replace `#!perl` with the correct shebang line.

```perl
if ( $Config{startperl} =~ m,^\#!.*/perl, ) {
    $interpreter = $Config{startperl};
    $interpreter =~ s,^\#!,,;
}
else {
    $interpreter = $Config{perlpath};
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is `$Config{perlpath}`.

If you want your code to be very portable you may have to append a file type to that value; this is described in the [`perlport`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlport.html#Command-names-versus-file-pathnames) documentation. Otherwise all you need is this:

```
use Config;
my $perl = $Config{perlpath};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get it via the core [Config](http://search.cpan.org/~flora/perl/configpm) module.

```
use Config;
say $Config{perl5};   # current perl binary
```

I *think* that should always contain an absolute path, but I can't guarantee it.

Comment: The documentation for `$Config{perl5}` is pretty unhelpful: "This variable contains the full path (if any) to a previously installed perl5.005 or later suitable for running the script to determine inc_version_list."

Comment: Using $Config{perl5} gives me the Perl that is first in my PATH, whereas $Config{perlpath} gives me the Perl that is currently executing.

Answer (score -1):

Perl includes the core module [File::Spec](http://p3rl.org/File%3a%3aSpec) which can translate relative paths to absolute paths.

```
my $full_path_to_perl = File::Spec->rel2abs($^X);
```

Comment: That's not going to work in a lot of cases. Often `$^X` just says `perl` in which case `rel2abs` will give you the path to the CWD, which is probably wrong.

Answer (score -1):

For perl6 (raku): `$*EXECUTABLE-NAME` contains full path of the currently running Raku interpreter (like `sys.executable` for Python)

To get the full command line:

```
say ($*EXECUTABLE-NAME, $*PROGRAM-NAME, |@*ARGS).join(' ');
```

More in [Variable Documentation](https://docs.perl6.org/language/variables#$*EXECUTABLE-NAME)

Comment: Perl is *not* Raku. The two are distinct languages, despite both residing in the same family of languages.

Comment: I was looking for the answer for Raku, found this post which led my way. I have no mean to harm Perl but you are rigth, next time I open a new post with a link to the Perl one (better for both).