# Get full path without resolving symlinks?

Tags: bash

How can I get the full path to a symlink without resolving it to the path of the original file?

For example, if I have a directory set up like this:

```
~$ tree analysis_results/
analysis_results/
`-- Sample1
    `-- bar.txt -> /Users/me/foo.txt
```

If I try to get the full path to `bar.txt`, I end up with the path to `foo.txt` instead:

```
~$ readlink -f analysis_results/Sample1/bar.txt
/Users/me/foo.txt
```

But what I really want is this:

```
/Users/me/analysis_results/Sample1/bar.txt
```

Is there a simple way to accomplish this? It looks like I do not have `realpath` available, not sure if that program does this, or if there is some other command that works like this.

Things get more complicated when my `pwd` is something like:

```
/Users/me/analysis/peaks/workflow/code
```

But I want to read the full path to a symlink like:

```
/Users/me/analysis/alignment/results/Sample1/bar.txt
```

Answer (score 6):

With GNU `realpath`:

```
$ touch foo
$ ln -s foo bar
$ realpath --no-symlinks bar
/path/to/bar
```

Comment: this sounds perfect, unfortunately `realpath` isn't available on my OS, CentOS 6 (just updated the OP with this information). I'll have to look into getting it installed.

Comment: @user5359531 You can also [do something similar in Perl](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16372849/2908724) if Centos YUM doesn't work out.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo "$(readlink -f analysis_results/Sample1)/bar.txt"
```

Resolve only the directory and then append the filename to the result.

Answer (score 1):

You want the full path with any intermediate symlinks resolved?

From the "yet another way to do it" category: Your pwd command probably has a "-P" option to print the physical path to a directory.  So, you could wrap a `cd` and `pwd` in `()` to get something like

```
user@host[/tmp]
$ mkdir test
user@host[/tmp]
$ ln -s test linkdir
user@host[/tmp]
$ (cd /tmp/linkdir; pwd -P)
/tmp/test
```

So, all you're doing is `cd $(dirname $yourfile)` and then running `pwd -P` to get the physical path to the parent directory.  It's wrapped in parens in the example so it creates a subshell and doesn't impact your current working directory.

Answer (score 0):

#### practical example

To get the parent path of a bash script folder,

- ...gladly ignoring that its folder is actually a symlink from somewhere else...

**This combination of [parameter substitution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/965072/444255), inner shell and realpath does the deed:**

For example, to 'include' `../something`. The inner `cd` goes out of scope with the backtick that follows.

```
echo $(realpath --no-symlinks `cd ..; echo $(pwd)`)
source $parentDir/helper-library.sh
```